# How to extract data into associative array from HTML table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, associative-array

Suppose I have HTML like this,

```
<table id="Words">
<tr>
    <td class="cell">Hello</td>
    <td class="desc">A word</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell">Bye</td>
    <td class="desc">A word</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell">Tricicle</td>
    <td class="desc">A toy</td>
</tr>
```

Is there any elegant way/function to convert this to Javascript associative array? How to go about it?

Comment: <pedant>Javascript doesn't have associative arrays only objects and numeric arrays (objects with numeric keys)</pedant>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('tr').map(function(){
    return {
        cell: $('.cell', this).text(),
        desc: $('.desc', this).text()
    }
})
```

---

```
jQuery(Object { cell="Hello", desc="A word"}, Object { cell="Bye", desc="A word"}, Object { cell="Tricicle", desc="A toy"})
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/cyFW5/ - here and it will works for every td with a class

```
$(function() {

    var arr = [],
        tmp;

    $('#Words tr').each(function() {

        tmp = {};

        $(this).children().each(function() {

            if ($(this).attr('class')) {
                tmp[$(this).attr('class')] = $(this).text();
            }

        });

        arr.push(tmp);
    });

    console.log(arr);

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = [];
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var row = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
        var cell = {};
        cell[$(this).attr('class')] = $(this).html();
        row.push(cell);
    });
    table.push(row);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WZETm/), watch the console.

```
$(function() {

    var words = [];

    $('#Words tr').each(function() {
        words.push({
            cell: $('.cell', this).text(),
            desc: $('.desc', this).text()
        });
    });

    console.log(words);

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this specific use case then this would work:

```
var results = {};
$('table#Words tr').each(function(i, x){
    results[i] = {
      desc: $(x).find('.desc').text(),
      cell: $(x).find('.cell').text()
    }
});
```

But why have the whole conversion to an object? What's it being used for, there might be an easier method of walking through the data.