# sending data to the server in a page using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery an dynamically creating number of rows.
if I want to send it to server how can I send that data.
I tried using form but that did not work

I am using the following code:

```
                 $(document).ready(function() {
        // Add button functionality
        $("table.dynatable button.add").click(function() {
            var master = $(this).parents("table.dynatable");
                         var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
            prot.attr("class", "")
            master.find("tbody").append(prot);
        });
```

In the body I have:

```
            <th>Numbere</th>
            <th><button class="add">Add</button></th>
        </tr>
```

Also here why do we need

```
        prot.attr("class", "")
```

I am able to add dynamically the number of entries I want. But having issue sending this data to the server using HTTP.

I want to use Ajax call but how to extract and get the data here.

```
$.ajax({
url: "/temp",
type: "post",
data: data,
dataType: "json",
contentType:
```

Comment: You are adding some new fields to the form. But you are using cloning so do you change names of those fields ? If not then there will be only one value in your http request

Comment: yes this is the problem I am looking how to address

Comment: Maybe you can use brackets in the prototype name i.e. `<input type='text' name='testField[]'>` It should help if you are using PHP on server side. If not you can use: `prot.attr('name', 'someNewName');` But remember that you should change id also

Comment: why won't a form work.... and then use `serialize()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract data from an HTML table to an associative array (JSON object) and then post it to the server

[How to extract data into associative array from HTML table using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136993/how-to-extract-data-into-associative-array-from-html-table-using-jquery)

http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-extract-data-from-html-lists-and-tables/

Comment: in my case I am using clone and my list is dynamic and all the variables are having the same name. than how to address this

Comment: @TheLearner it shouldn't matter as long as you are iterating all the rows correctly. can you share what you have already tried?